# How I can use travel_to rails helper method with relative time

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to use travel_to helper method to with relative time i.e (4.days ago) but it gives error like

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `ago'
```

here is code:

```
travel_to 4.days ago do
  Time.now
end
```

Comment: it's was syntax error. It would be travel_to 4.days.ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ago` is a `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` method, so It should be `4.days.ago`.